# Unable to get value of variable in yii model function

Tags: php, yii, model

Unable to get value of variable in a function. While I print `$this->var`, it gives me empty. Is there something I am missing in these steps?

```
class ModelFile extends CoreModel{

 public $var;
 public $var2;

 public function setId() {
  $this->var = '123';
 }

 public function getId(){
  $this->setId();
  var_dump($this->var); //Empty
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
class ModelFile extends CoreModel{

    public $var;
    public $var2;

    public function setId() {
       $this->var = '123';
    }

    public function getId(){
      $this->setId();
      var_dump($this->var); //Empty
    }
 }
 **create an object of the above class and call the function getId() then it 
 will execute and print the var**

 $model = new ModelFile();
 $model->getId();
```